# Class 'Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message' not found in "Message.proto"

Tags: php, docker, protocol-buffers, pecl, protoc

I'm working on a project with [protocol buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf) and after i compiled a proto file, i cant seem to include it neither run it cos it keeps giving me this exact error: 
`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message' not found in /app/generated_files/message.php on line 13`

On `message.php` i have the auto generated file from a `.proto` file and it includes `Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message`.

While reading on the [protobuf github issues](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2336), i found that a person had the same problem where he concluded that it was the composer's fault. However in my case that wouldnt be the issue cos i didnt use composer.

I used pecl to install protocol buffers, and i have the library `protobuf.so` located in `/etc/php5/apache2/XXXXXXXXX`. I also added `extension=protobuf.so` on the last line of php.ini.

Keep in mind that im using docker for everything, therefore it might be something different but i still doubt.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone ends up here with the same question: you just need to add componser autoloader to your file `include_once './vendor/autoload.php';` (change path as required)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the reason was different for me:
Git somehow messed up the casing of the folders, which lead to a wrong file path translation.
As soon as I fixed the casing ([...]/src/Google/Protobuf instead of [...]/src/google/protobuf in the vendor folder)